# chromedriver opens a website then immediately crashes using selenium 4 in vs code

Tags: python, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.ieltsadvantage.com/writing-task-1/")
```

after running the code it opens a website but immediately crashes and window closes

Answer (score 0):

With `selenium 4` you need to set the "detach" option to True when starting chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions() # Create options
opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True) # add detach
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=opts) # bind options in Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.ieltsadvantage.com/writing-task-1/")
```

However, `executable_path` is deprecated. Here's an updated code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_executable = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(executable_path=PATH) # use services instead
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_executable, options=opts) # bind service
driver.get("https://www.ieltsadvantage.com/writing-task-1/")
```